# Login problem after migrating to Azure APIM new developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I migrated to new dev portal and users cannot login to the new dev portal using their old username and password. Please what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I test in my side but all users can login to new dev portal and old dev portal with their username and password. For your problem, please check if you choose "**Deprecated developer portal**" when you invite the user.
[image]

And please also do publish operation again and then try to login to new dev portal.